# "Innocent" vs. "immature"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, differences, word-usage

I'm trying to decide how to describe someone. He is not very wise, but that is also due to his ignorance. Should I use "innocence" or "immature" and can someone please explain the difference between these two phrases?

Comment: I don't think there is anything like enough context in this question. There must be dozens if not hundreds of possible words for people who aren't very wise. And it's hard to see how anyone could be wise if they are ignorant, so that doesn't tell us much more. This is not a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your explanation, I'm not sure I would choose either word. 
Some other options:

- inexperienced
- ingenuous
- unsophisticated
- naive

I think I would go with [naive.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/naive)  It's often used as a synonym for "gullible", but its original sense seems perfect here.

Comment: +1 for naïve. Exactly the right word to describe the person in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Using *immature* would give the idea that a person has the ability to show wisdom, but are not doing so in a situation.

Using *innocent* would portray a person that is more simple in nature, and possible unable to show wisdom in certain situations.

Adam Sandler in *The Waterboy* is innocent, while Adam Sandler in *Happy Gilmore* is immature.

Comment: Ah, but what is he in _The Wedding Singer?_

Answer (score 1):

Both of these words can certainly be used to describe someone who is not very wise, but **[immature](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/immature)** means undeveloped, and **[innocent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/innocent)** means unsophisticated.

If you are talking about someone who is ignorant because they are young and inexperienced, I'd suggest *immature*.  However, if you are talking about someone who is ignorant because they have been sheltered from the world, I'd say *innocent* is more appropriate.  Either way, I think *innocent* is slightly less offensive than *immature*.

If you want some other suggestions, *[unrefined](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unrefined)* or *[provincial](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/provincial)* might do.

Answer (score 0):

Innocent can also be used to describe the appearance, means friendly, cute or at least not looks like a bad person.

> He looks innocent.
>
> He is innocent looking.

Immature is used to describe someone looks young, childish or mentally naive.

I will go with "immature".